# XSLT: How to match on first or second occurrence of element depending on level

Tags: xslt-2.0

I need to match on the first div with class name row-1 that is inside another div with also class name row-1. This is easy enough. But the problem is sometimes the first div with class name row-1 is the only div with that class name. And when that happens I need to match on it.

The xml can look like this: Scenario 1

```
<div class="row-1">
    <div class="someClassName">
        <div class="row-1">content</div> (match this one)
        <div class="row-1">content</div>
        <div class="row-1">content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or like this: Scenario 2

```
<div class="row-1"> (match this one)
    <div class="someClassName">
        <div class="somOtherClassName">content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This markup will be several levels deep in the document (meaning there will be other divs surrounding this).

This is the xsl to match in the first scenario:

```
<xsl:template match="//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' row-1 ')]//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' row-1 ')][position() = 1]">
```

But how will the xsl look when I need to check for both? Only one scenario can occur at a time. I tried using xsl:choose, but it's not allowed to have template:match inside those.

Any advice is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
It seems this works for scenario 2:

```
<xsl:template match="//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' row-1 ')][not(descendant::div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' row-1 ')])][not(ancestor::div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' row-1 ')])]">
```

However this seems a bit verbose. If someone has a better way of doing this, then please let me know.

Comment: ```<xsl:template match="//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' row-1 ')]//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' row-1 ')][position() = 1] | //div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' row-1 ')]/div[@class='someClassName']/div[@class='someOtherClassName']">``` ?

Comment: In your first example there are inner `div`s with `@class="row-1"`. All of these do match your Scenario 2 condition as they don't have any inner `div`s. Don't you want to select them based on the Scenario 2?

Comment: @Lingamurthy CS 
Not sure I understand you. The xsl I provided takes care of scenario 1. But it will not work for scenario 2. 
So I need this: If there is only on instance of row-1 in the document then match that one. But if it has one or more descendants with class name row-1, then match the first one of those descendants.

Comment: A leading `//` in a pattern is never necessary so you can at least shorten the `match="//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' row-1 ')]...` to `match="div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' row-1 ')]`

Comment: @Martin Honnen  Thank you, will do so :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the task correctly, you need to match the first div with class "row-1" in the document that doesn't contain other divs with class "row-1" at any level of nesting. You can use XPath "is" operator with descendant axis to select the first occurrence of necessary element in the document:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:t="stackoverflow.com"    
               version="2.0">


    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="attribute()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="div[. is (//div)[t:is-row1-div(.)][empty(descendant::div[t:is-row1-div(.)])][1]]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="attribute()"/>
            <xsl:text>(Matched) </xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:function name="t:is-row1-div" as="xs:boolean">
        <xsl:param name="div" as="element(div)"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="boolean($div/@class eq 'row-1')"/>
    </xsl:function>


</xsl:transform>
```

You can test this transform here: http://xsltransform.net/ejivdH3